R: Coloring ggplot with 2 colors to indicate ties?
I have this map of North Carolina. I randomly assigned different colors to each county (such that each county only has 1 color) and made the following map (R: Using the MATCH function as a JOIN?):
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

set.seed(123)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange")
favorite_color <- sample(colors, nrow(nc), replace = TRUE)
my_df <- data.frame(NAME = nc$NAME, favorite_color)

nc_merged <- merge(nc, my_df, by = "NAME", all.x = TRUE)


ggplot(data = nc_merged) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = favorite_color)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colors) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Favorite Color by County",
       fill = "Favorite Color")


Next, I made this map in which a county can have more than one favorite color. In this case, those counties are left white:
set.seed(123)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange")
favorite_color <- replicate(nrow(nc), {
    sample_size <- sample(1:3, 1)
    sample(colors, sample_size, replace = FALSE)
})

my_df <- data.frame(NAME = nc$NAME, favorite_color = sapply(favorite_color, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")))

my_df$favorite_color[sapply(favorite_color, length) > 1] <- NA

nc_merged <- merge(nc, my_df, by = "NAME", all.x = TRUE)

ggplot(data = nc_merged) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = favorite_color)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c(colors, "white"), na.value = "white") +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Favorite Color by County (with Ties)",
         fill = "Favorite Color")


My Question: In the case where counties have tied colors (e.g. 2 ties, 3 ties), is it possible to somehow blend these colors together to make a new color? I.e. where there are no ties, color it one color - and where there are ties, blend the colors together?
I tried to do this with ggpattern:
set.seed(123)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange")
favorite_color <- replicate(nrow(nc), {
    sample_size <- sample(1:3, 1)
    sample(colors, sample_size, replace = FALSE)
})

my_df <- data.frame(NAME = nc$NAME, 
                    favorite_color = sapply(favorite_color, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")))

unique_patterns <- unique(my_df$favorite_color)
pattern_colors <- setNames(rainbow(length(unique_patterns)), unique_patterns)

nc_merged <- merge(nc, my_df, by = "NAME", all.x = TRUE)

ggplot(data = nc_merged) +
    geom_sf_pattern(aes(fill = favorite_color, pattern_fill = favorite_color),
                    pattern = "stripe", color = "black", size = 0.2) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = pattern_colors) +
    scale_pattern_fill_manual(values = pattern_colors) +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Favorite Color by County (with Patterns for Ties)",
         fill = "Favorite Color")


But this is looking very difficult to read. Can someone please suggest what to do?
Thanks!
Edit: An alternate way, still not ideal...
library(ggpattern)


set.seed(123)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange")
favorite_color <- replicate(nrow(nc), {
    sample_size <- sample(1:3, 1)
    sample(colors, sample_size, replace = FALSE)
})

my_df <- data.frame(
    NAME = nc$NAME, 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

for(i in 1:3) {
    my_df[[paste0("color", i)]] <- sapply(favorite_color, function(x) if(length(x) >= i) x[i] else NA)
}

my_df$color_count <- sapply(favorite_color, length)

nc_merged <- merge(nc, my_df, by = "NAME", all.x = TRUE)

nc_merged$pattern <- ifelse(nc_merged$color_count == 2, "stripe", "crosshatch")

ggplot() +
    # Layer for counties with a single color
    geom_sf(data = subset(nc_merged, color_count == 1), 
            aes(fill = color1), 
            color = "white") +
    # Layer for counties with two colors
    geom_sf_pattern(data = subset(nc_merged, color_count == 2),
                    aes(fill = color1, 
                        pattern_fill = color2),
                    pattern = "stripe",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    color = "white",
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
    # Layer for counties with three colors
    geom_sf_pattern(data = subset(nc_merged, color_count == 3),
                    aes(fill = color1,
                        pattern_fill = color2),
                    pattern = "crosshatch",
                    pattern_angle = 45,
                    color = "white",
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                    pattern_key_scale_factor = 0.6) +
    geom_sf_pattern(data = subset(nc_merged, color_count == 3),
                    aes(pattern_fill = color3),
                    pattern = "crosshatch",
                    pattern_angle = 135,
                    color = NA,
                    pattern_density = 0.5,
                    pattern_spacing = 0.01) +
    scale_fill_identity() +
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title = "Favorite Color by County (with Patterns for Ties)")



I think with the number of counties there, anything you do will be difficult to follow. However, perhaps changing the opacity would work?

@ Kat: Thank you so much for your reply! Do you have any ideas how I might be able to do this? Would love to see your answer...

Some ideas? https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-geometry.html

@ Kat: I am planning to put a bounty on this question tomorrow

Choices regarding appropriate elements for any cartographic representation should be driven by the data. However, based on your example, it's not really clear what your 'real world' use case would be (see Allan's comment). There is likely to be a much more appropriate method for representing your data, but  without further context, it would be a guess. Could you edit your question and explain a bit more about your actual data?

Another option is to gradient the colors in the shared color states, but it's still a bit unruly to read or interpret.
You'll need to add the library ggnewscale

Did you notice that in your legend, red is labeled blue? (None of the colors are aligned correctly.) This is a sorting issue (sort colors before assigning it to values). You'll see this modified in my code.

When favorite_color and therefore my_df were created, any counties that had split geometries (e.g., Craven, Carteret, etc.) were listed more than one time. These counties have conflicting color assignments. You have 108 rows in my_df, but there are only 100 counties in NC.
This is how I addressed this issue in your code for these 2 frames:
favorite_color <- replicate(length(unique(nc$NAME)), { # note `length...`
  sample_size <- sample(1:3, 1)
  sample(colors, sample_size, replace = FALSE)
})

my_df <- data.frame(NAME = unique(nc$NAME),            # note `unique...`
                    favorite_color = sapply(
                      favorite_color, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")))

Since wiping out the colors with NA wouldn't work for this code, I've added another column that keeps the original color data before it's swapped for NA in your code.
my_df$fc2 <- my_df$favorite_color   # keep full color data

The approach I use here is a bit ungainly and it takes a hot minute to process before the plot renders.
Step 1:
Build grids for the gradients in states with more than one color.
This is derived from another SO answer.
In this UDF, the first function includes an argument called cellsize. The smaller you make these values, the better the gradient will look. However, the smaller you make these values, the longer it will take to render the plot.
gradPoly <- function(mp) {        # create grid squares within shape to gradient
  my_mp <- st_make_grid(mp, cellsize = c(.05, .05)) 
  long <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(my_mp, warn = F))[, 1]
  return(st_sf(longitude = long, geometry = my_mp) %>% 
           st_intersection(st_geometry(mp)))
}   # this code will render a warning in the console

Step 2:
Build gradient color scales for states with more than one color.
scaler <- function(mp, plt) {
  wds = strsplit(mp$fc2, ', ')[[1]]  # extract colors assigned
  val = length(wds)                  # quantity of colors assigned
  ifelse(val < 3,                    # 2 colors or 3 colors in the gradient
         return(plt + scale_fill_gradient(low = wds[1], high = wds[2], guide = "none")),
         return(plt + scale_fill_gradient2(low = wds[1], mid = wds[2], high = wds[3], guide = "none",
                                                midpoint = median(gradPoly(mp)$longitude))))
}

Step 3:
Identify the counties with more than one color assigned.
# which counties have more than one fave?
these <- filter(my_df, is.na(favorite_color)) %>% select(NAME) %>% 
  arrange(NAME) %>% unlist()

Step 4:
Build an empty plot to build off of. You'll add borders to the geom_sf at the end, so it's the top layer.
plt <- ggplot(data = nc_merged) +      # essentially the code from the question
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Favorite Color by County (with Ties)",
       fill = "Favorite Color")

Step 5:
Add the county gradient for each applicable county. This code will take a hot minute to complete; it will also take a bit to render the plot.
for(j in unique(these)) {      # for each county with more than one favorite
  dta <- filter(nc_merged, NAME == j)     # extract county data                       # more than one color
  plt <- plt + new_scale_fill() +         # add to existing plot
    geom_sf(data = gradPoly(dta),         # call the function gradPoly()
            aes(fill = longitude), color = NA) # build gradient grid
  plt <- scaler(dta, plt)                 # add gradient for grid with scaler()
}

Step 6:
Add the remaining 1-color counties and the borders to the plot.
(plt <- plt + new_scale_fill() + new_scale_color() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = favorite_color), color = "black") +   # from question
  scale_fill_manual(values = sort(colors), na.value = NA)) # values modified

The plot (grid cells .05 x .05) (1.08 min to render)

Just to give you an idea of what changing the grid cell size does, here's the same plot, but with cellsize = c(.01, .01) (1.9 min to render)

All the code used, all in one place
(easier copy + paste)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

# code from question
nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>%
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

set.seed(123)
colors <- c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple", "orange")
favorite_color <- replicate(length(unique(nc$NAME)), { # <- I ADDED: unique NAME only
  sample_size <- sample(1:3, 1)
  sample(colors, sample_size, replace = FALSE)
})

my_df <- data.frame(
  NAME = unique(nc$NAME),               # <---- I ADDED: unique NAME only
  favorite_color = sapply(favorite_color, 
                          function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")))

my_df$fc2 <- my_df$favorite_color       # <---- I ADDED: keep full color data
my_df$favorite_color[sapply(favorite_color, length) > 1] <- NA

nc_merged <- merge(nc, my_df, by = "NAME", all.x = TRUE)

gradPoly <- function(mp) { # create grid squares for gradient
  my_mp <- st_make_grid(mp, cellsize = c(.05, .05)) 
  long <- st_coordinates(st_centroid(my_mp, warn = F))[, 1]
  return(st_sf(longitude = long, geometry = my_mp) %>% 
           st_intersection(st_geometry(mp)))
}

scaler <- function(mp, plt) {
  wds = strsplit(mp$fc2, ', ')[[1]]  # extract colors assigned
  val = length(wds)                  # quantity of colors assigned
  ifelse(val < 3,                    # 2 colors or 3 colors in the gradient
         return(plt + scale_fill_gradient(low = wds[1], high = wds[2], guide = "none")),
         return(plt + scale_fill_gradient2(low = wds[1], mid = wds[2], high = wds[3], guide = "none",
                                                midpoint = median(gradPoly(mp)$longitude))))
}

# which counties have more than one fave?
these <- filter(my_df, is.na(favorite_color)) %>% select(NAME) %>% 
  arrange(NAME) %>% unlist()

plt <- ggplot(data = nc_merged) +      # essentially the code from the question
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Favorite Color by County (with Ties)",
       fill = "Favorite Color")

for(j in unique(these)) {      # for each county with more than one favorite
  dta <- filter(nc_merged, NAME == j)     # extract county data                       # more than one color
  plt <- plt + new_scale_fill() +         # add to existing plot
    geom_sf(data = gradPoly(dta),         # call the function gradPoly()
            aes(fill = longitude), color = NA) # build gradient grid
  plt <- scaler(dta, plt)                 # add gradient for grid with scaler()
}

(plt <- plt + new_scale_fill() + new_scale_color() +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = favorite_color), color = "black") +   # from question
    scale_fill_manual(values = sort(colors), na.value = NA)) # values modified


This little function will blend a vector of colors into a single color:
mixer <- function(colors) {
  paste0("#",
    col2rgb(colors) |>
      rowMeans() |>
      round() |>
      as.raw() |> 
      as.character() |> 
      paste0(collapse = ""))
}

So if you take your data frame with tied colors, you can do:
my_df <- my_df %>% 
  summarise(actual_color = mixer(favorite_color), 
            favorite_color = paste(favorite_color, collapse = " + "),
            .by = NAME)

nc_merged <- merge(nc, my_df, by = "NAME", all.x = TRUE)

ggplot(data = nc_merged) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = favorite_color)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = setNames(unique(my_df[-1])[[1]], 
                                      unique(my_df[-1])[[2]])) +
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title = "Favorite Color by County",
       fill = "Favorite Color")



@ Allan Cameron: thank you so much for your answer!

Do you think ggpattern might be a good choice?

@stats_noob honestly, no. ggpattern is great for some use cases, but In data viz terms the image is already complex and difficult to interpret. I think a patterned fill will make this worse rather than better. Perhaps knowing the real use-case would allow a better recommendation for what would work well here.
